# AESFast: Okay - response when I try to parse a HTML file, what does it mean?

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup, aes

I am following [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2014/09/how-to-parse-html-file-in-java-jsoup-example.html) , because I am trying to learn how to parse a Html file.

So when I try to run this code, from the example :

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;




public class Parse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //1
     String HTMLSTring = "<!DOCTYPE html>" 
                        + "<html>" 
                        + "<head>" 
                        + "<title>JSoup Example</title>" 
                        + "</head>" 
                        + "<body>" 
                        + "<table><tr><td><h1>HelloWorld</h1></tr>" 
                        + "</table>" 
                        + "</body>" 
                        + "</html>";

     Document html = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring); 

     String title = html.title(); 
     String h1 = html.body().getElementsByTag("h1").text();

     System.out.println("firts thing:");
     System.out.println("Input HTML String to JSoup :" + HTMLSTring);
     System.out.println("After parsing, Title : " + title);
     System.out.println("Afte parsing, Heading : " + h1);

     //2
     Document doc;
     try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get(); 
         title = doc.title(); 
         } catch (IOException e) 
         { 
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         } 
     System.out.println("Second thing, reading html page from a URL document: ");
     System.out.println("Jsoup Can read HTML page from URL, title : " + title);

    //3
    // JSoup Example 3 - Parsing an HTML file in Java //
     //Document htmlFile = Jsoup.parse("login.html", "ISO-8859-1"); 
     // wrong 

     Document htmlFile = null;
     try { 
         htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(new File("login.html"), "ISO-8859-1");
         } catch (IOException e) 
            { 
             e.printStackTrace();
             } // right 

         title = htmlFile.title(); 
         Element div = htmlFile.getElementById("login"); 
         String cssClass = div.className(); 
         // getting class form HTML element 
         System.out.println("Jsoup can also parse HTML file directly"); 
         System.out.println("title : " + title); 
         System.out.println("class of div tag : " + cssClass); 
     }

    }
```

I get in the console this response : `AESFast: Okay` .
 I have no idea what it means and I can't find something relevant to help me solve this situation.

I should get something like this:

```
Input HTML String to JSoup :<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>JSoup Example</title></head><body><table><tr><td><h1>HelloWorld</h1></tr></table></body></html> 
After parsing, Title : JSoup Example 
Afte parsing, Heading : HelloWorld 
Jsoup Can read HTML page from URL, title : Google 
Jsoup can also parse HTML file directly 
title : Login Page 
class of div tag : simple
```

**EDIT** 
I re-downloaded eclipse and now I get the output ok, but I still don't know what happened.